# Connecting to an HTTPS service with SproutCore

Tags: javascript, https, sproutcore

I'm building a web app that requires me to connect to a service (https) to get some data. The web app is to be built using SproutCore. Now, I'm super new to SproutCore, and haven't been able to get to connect to the service. Some folks on the irc channel were super helpful and told me that to connect to an https service, I need to add a line in my BUILDFILE that says:

`proxy '/path', :to => "https://myWebService.com", :secure => true`

I did that. However, if I try to navigate to the url using:

`SC.Request.getUrl('/path').notify(this, 'notifyMe').send();`

I get a 404:
 GET http://localhost:4020/path 404 (Not Found).

Any idea as to how I can connect to my HTTPS service. Additionally, I would like to state that once I connect, I would need to authenticate with it using basic auth (username and password).

Thanks all!

EDIT: Just wanted to mention that this request is Cross-Domain. I was under the impression that GET worked just fine cross domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
proxy '/path', :to => "https://myWebService.com", :secure => true
```

to

```
proxy '/', :to => "myWebService.com", :secure => true
```

then

```
SC.Request.getUrl('/path').notify(this, 'notifyMe').send();
```

should work

Comment: Nope. myWebservice is the url and not actually a web service I have written. It is a webservice which has been existing for the past few years and I wish to get data from it. All my native apps are using that service. This is the 1st time I'm making a webapp, and it needs that service too. I have tried doing:
`proxy '/path', :to => "myWebService.com", :secure => true`
`proxy '/path', :to => "https://myWebService.com", :secure => true`
`proxy '/path', :to => "myWebService.com", :protocol => 'https', :secure => true`

And none of them worked. :(

Comment: Ok, in the command prompt running sc-server what is the url being shown there? You should be able to see something like `PROXY https://myWebservice.com/path 404 `

Comment: Hmm. I cannot see that. The 404 I saw was on the browser console. The term window shows me: `SproutCore v1.6.0.1 Development Server
Starting server at http://0.0.0.0:4020 in debug mode
To quit sc-server, press Control-C
>> Thin web server (v1.2.11 codename Bat-Shit Crazy)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4020, CTRL+C to stop`

Comment: I wasn't aware that it was supposed to update the term window. >_<

Comment: Ok, we are getting closer to the issue.  Is the proxy info in the build file in the directory where you are running sc-server?

Comment: Nope it is in the buildfile that is in my apps directory. AND HOLY MOTHER OF APPROPRIATE IMPRECATIONS! I just got a login prompt! The server needs an http auth. You sir are brilliant!!! *worships* 2 days and this is finally getting answered!

Comment: FYI, I changed the proxy to go to the main buildfile and restarted the server. :)

Comment: I have a couple more questions; do I need to create separate questions or can I ask them here? Again, super thanks for your reply! You have no idea how grateful I am! You just relieved me of a huge problem. :D

Comment: Glad to help. You can name your first child after me ;)

Comment: I will, as soon as I decide to have one. :D But if you are in NYC, lunch is on me! :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157016/basic-authentication-in-sproutcore-sc-request Next question. :)