# Basic Authentication in SproutCore SC.Request

Tags: javascript, https, sproutcore

Thanks to  IAbstractDownvoteFactory for an awesome answer to my previous question

[Connecting to an HTTPS service with SproutCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155461/connecting-to-an-https-service-with-sproutcore)

This question is based off that. My question being, the server needs me to log in. Now, for dev reasons, I don't need the user to fill out the form. Additionally, even when this app is released, the user will NOT need to log in.

Thus, the username and password is only for dev purposes. However, it is there, and I don't want to see the browser popUp window. Is there any way in which I can handle authentication in the callback function?

Again, any help will be greatly appreciated! :D

Comment: I have no clue how to accomplish this one, sorry

Comment: No problems. :) I'll be pinging the IRC too. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SC.Request](https://github.com/sproutcore/sproutcore/blob/master/frameworks/ajax/system/request.js) supports the `header(key, value)` function so you can try injecting the basic authentication header yourself.

Set the key to "Authorization" and the value to base64_encode("username:password").

`Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==`

Comment: That actually worked. I was trying the same thing with "Authentication" instead of "Authorization". >_< Thanks!